# Error in Play Framework when adding more than one regex in a route path

Tags: java, playframework

I'm struggling to create a route with two url parameters with Play! Framework. I use the embedded version of Play server, described [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaRoutingDsl).

Everything works as expected when I use only one regular expression in my route path, like below.

`routingDsl.GET("/part1/$foo<[a-z]+>/part2/:bar").routeTo((foo, bar) -> 
     Results.ok("foo=" + foo + "   foo=" + bar));`

But I get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` exception when I add a second one like the following code snippet.

`routingDsl.GET("/part1/$foo<[a-z]+>/part2/$bar<[a-z]+>").routeTo((foo, bar) -> 
     Results.ok("foo=" + foo + "   foo=" + bar));`

**Stacktrace**

`Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path contains 1 params but function of arity 2 was passed
    at play.routing.RoutingDsl.with(RoutingDsl.java:271)
    at play.routing.RoutingDsl.access$000(RoutingDsl.java:93)
    at play.routing.RoutingDsl$PathPatternMatcher.build(RoutingDsl.java:477)`

**Environment**

- Java: 8
- Scala: 2.12
- Play! version: 2.6.12

Comment: If you wanted to declare it in the `routes` file; how would it look like? You just want to get the lower case alphabets?

Comment: I never used `routes` file. I only experimented with embedded Play server. Regex had been simplified for the question.